# Oracle SQL to Sort Version Numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, rdbms, version-sort

In Oracle, just using the `ORDER BY` does not sort version numbers.
My `Version_Number` field is declared as a `VARCHAR` and I cannot change it.
For Example: The following versions :

```
1.20  
1.9   
1.18  
1.13  
1.5   
1.11  
2.0  
1.8   
1.3   
1.2   
1.1   
1.0   
1.10
```

**should be sorted as**

```
2.0   
1.20  
1.18  
1.13 
1.11 
1.10  
1.9   
1.8   
1.5  
1.3   
1.2   
1.1 
1.0
```

I have researched several posts but none of them seem to really serve my purpose or the answers were intended for SQL Server, etc and not Oracle. I came across this particular sql which seemed to look like it worked.

```
select version_number from mytable 
order by lpad(version_number, 4) desc;
```

which sorted the versions in this fashion:

```
1.20    
1.18   
1.13   
1.11   
1.10   
2.0    
1.9    
1.8   
1.5     
1.3    
1.2    
1.1    
1.0
```

I believe this sql statement works for `SQL Server` :

```
select version_number from mytable 
order by cast ('/' + replace(version_number , '.', '/') + '/' as hierarchyid) desc;
```

However, this does not work with Oracle. Is there an alternative to hierarchyid in Oracle? 
 
 
Is there anyone who can come up with a SQL to sort these versions accurately?

I have already seen the posts mentioned below (links attached). So kindly do not tell me that this post is a duplicate. 
[SQL sort by version "number", a string of varying length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528830/sql-sort-by-version-number-a-string-of-varying-length) 
[How Can I Sort A 'Version Number' Column Generically Using a SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query) 
[Version number sorting in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870945/version-number-sorting-in-sql-server) 
[mysql sorting of version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508313/mysql-sorting-of-version-numbers) 
and many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do it. First order by the number before `.` and then by the numbers after `.`

```
select version_number 
from mytable 
order by substr(version_number, 1, instr(version_number,'.')-1) desc
        ,length(substr(version_number, instr(version_number,'.')+1)) desc
        ,substr(version_number, instr(version_number,'.')+1) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is sorting it in this way: 2.0,
1.9,
1.8,
1.7,
1.6,
1.5,
1.4,
1.3,
1.20,
1.2,
1.19,
1.18,
1.17,
1.16,
1.15,
1.14,
1.13,
1.12,
1.11,
1.10,
1.1,
1.0

Comment: Do you think you could tweak it a little bit to handle the sorting in the case when there is no decimal point in the version? For example: if there is a "1" , it displays this way : 1,
1.20,
1.18,
1.17,
1.16, 1.10,
1.9, 1.2,
1.1,
1.0

Answer (score 3):

This SQL supports your input data plus any included Revision or Build digits.

```
with 
   inputs as (select '1.20'         as version_number from dual union all  
              select '1.9'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.18'         as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.13'         as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.5'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.11'         as version_number from dual union all
              select '2.0'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.8'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.3'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.2'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.1'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.0'          as version_number from dual union all
              select '1.10'         as version_number from dual union all
              select ' 3.1 '        as version_number from dual union all
              select '3.1.1000'     as version_number from dual union all
              select '3.1.1'        as version_number from dual union all
              select '3.1.100'      as version_number from dual union all
              select '3.1.2.1000'   as version_number from dual union all
              select '3.1.2.1'      as version_number from dual union all
              select '3.1.2.100 '   as version_number from dual)
,versions as  (select  trim(version_number) as version_number,
        nvl(LPAD(trim(regexp_substr(version_number, '[^.]+', 1, 1)),5,'0'),'00000') AS Major,
        nvl(LPAD(trim(regexp_substr(version_number, '[^.]+', 1, 2)),5,'0'),'00000') AS Minor, 
        nvl(LPAD(trim(regexp_substr(version_number, '[^.]+', 1, 3)),5,'0'),'00000') AS Revision, 
        nvl(LPAD(trim(regexp_substr(version_number, '[^.]+', 1, 4)),5,'0'),'00000') AS Build 
        from inputs 
        ORDER BY Major desc, Minor desc, Revision desc, Build desc)
--select * from versions; 
select version_number from versions;
```

Remove the -- to see the intermediate result.

For OP, replace "inputs as (select ... from dual)" with:

```
   inputs as (select version_number from mytable)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joel Coehoorn suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/528839/6340496), "refactor version number storage so that each section has it's own column: MajorVersion, MinorVersion, Revision, Build".

I'm re-posting as I found this *very* helpful!

To expand, I was looking to get the `MAX` version number, and ended up using this script along with Joel's suggestion.

```
    -- GET MAX VERSION NUMBER
    SELECT
        REPLACE(vnum, ' ', '') AS versionum
    FROM
        (SELECT
            MAX(LPAD(major, 4) || '.' || LPAD(minor, 4) || '.' || LPAD(revision, 4)) AS vnum
        FROM
            my_table
        ORDER BY
            major
          , minor
          , revision
        ) tbl1
```