# LPAD and REGEXP_REPLACE interaction gone wonky?

Tags: regex, oracle

got something here I can't explain, hoping to get some help seeing what I'm obviously missing :)

While working on a solution for this question:
[Oracle SQL to Sort Version Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000375/oracle-sql-to-sort-version-numbers#34000431)

I figured a clever regexp_replace + LPAD would results in a nicer sorted value. However, for some reason the LPAD kept misbehaving.  Here's the "issue" in a simplified test:

```
  with w_data as (
     select '9'  v  from dual union all
     select '18' v  from dual
     )
  select v,
         lpad(v, 4, '0' ) a,
         regexp_replace(v, '([0-9]*)', lpad('\1', 4, '0')) b
  from w_data
  /

  V  
  -- 
  A
  ----
  B
  ----------
  9  
  0009
  00900

  18 
  0018
  001800


  2 rows selected.
```

so as you can see, column "a" behaves as expected .. a length 4 string, with 0's padded on left ..

However, once it goes through the regexp_replace ... it starts to get weird ... why does it behave like that ?
How do I use it in conjunction with regexp_replace "properly" ?
(note that my regular expression and string - as per the linked question - is a bit more complex ;) )

[edit]
tried with "[0-9]+" .. still not padding properly though ..

```
  with w_data as (
     select '9'  v  from dual union all
     select '18' v  from dual
     )
  select v,
         lpad(v, 4, '0' ) a,
         regexp_replace(v, '([0-9]+)', lpad('\1', 4, '0')) b
  from w_data
  /

  V  
  -- 
  A
  ----
  B
  ----------
  9  
  0009
  009

  18 
  0018
  0018


  2 rows selected.
```

Note that the 18 comes out correctly ("0018") , however, the 9 comes out as "009" only 3 characters? should be four:  "0009" ...

Comment: can you format better the sample, I dont understand what you want. Even when is OK refer to another question, you should always post all relevant code here. You never know if someone delete the other question

Comment: Note that `[0-9]*` can match an empty location before each non-matching sequence/symbol, I think you need `[0-9]+`.

Comment: sorry .. meant column "a" behaves normally ... expecting a 4 string character result ...

Comment: @stribizhev:  + is better .. but still not quite .. let me update

Comment: It is impossible to pass a backreference in the replacement pattern of regexp_replace. You need to find another way to do that.

Comment: so I can't use LPAD there ? I have to "finish" regexp first? then send the results of that back to Lpad ? (for example?)  :(  bummer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LPAD doesn't understand the special syntax of regular expression substitution; that only has meaning when directly passed to a REGEXP function.  So this expression:

```
lpad('\1', 4, '0')
```

is simply going to return the string '00\1'.  That string is then passed to REGEXP_REPLACE, which interprets the '\1' in the regular expression context.

Comment: ahhh ... ok, that makes sense ... O.o    so best "workaround" might be:  `lpad(regexp_replace(v, '([0-9]+)', '\1'),4,'0')`  ??

Comment: That REGEXP_REPLACE call is a no-op, I think.  Each match of the regular expression is replaced with itself.  Are you trying to remove non-numeric characters from the input string?

Comment: ultimately (as per the link to that other question), I'm trying to sort a string version of 9 and 18 "better", by turning them into "0009" and "0018" .. the regex comes in because it's playing with versions (ie 1.9, 1.18, etc) ;) So I'm trying to turn 1.9 into "0001.0009" (for example) ... and then it'll sort vs "0001.0018" better.  (I know even regex to get me in trouble :) so I'm always looking for tasks like this to learn/practice ) :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are sure that all numbers would be no more than 4 digits, you can use this:

```
with w_data as (
   select '9'  v  from dual union all
   select '18' v  from dual
   )
select v,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(v, '([0-9]+)', '000\1'),
         '(0*)([0-9]{4})', 
         '\2') b
from w_data
```

If not, here is more complex solution:

```
with w_data as (
   select '9'  v  from dual union all
   select '18'  v  from dual union all
   select '123456' v  from dual
   )
select v,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(v, '([0-9]+)', '000\1'),
         '(0*)([1-9]?[0-9]{4})', 
         '\2') b
from w_data
```

Comment: This is great. Just used the same method to create a function for MySQL/MariaDB [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602292/5563083).

Comment: Great! I just had to write `\\1` instead of `\1`. My DB Version: `10.2.21-MariaDB-1:10.2.21+maria~bionic`