# Order by in `varchar` field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a field type `varchar`. Under this field, I have data something like this:

```
2       
100     
5.40    
MH90    
2 1/2   
2 1/4
```

I need to order this column in asc order.

```
2   
2 1/2   
2 1/4   
5.40
100     
MH90
```

I have used following lines for the order by. But this is not giving me order i need.

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(state) ASC, state ASC
```

Comment: @SougataBose, while `CAST`, `CONVERT` or `BIN` are obvious approaches, the link provided does not solve the problem to push `MH90` at the bottom.

Comment: `SELECT 
 s.char_field, 
 BIN(s.char_field) AS b
FROM 
 strings AS s 
ORDER BY 
 BIN(s.char_field) = 0, 
 BIN(s.char_field), 
 LENGTH(s.char_field)`

Comment: For natural sort with MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10 you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602292/5563083)

Comment: @Paul thanks, I solved it by using the natsort to the final resullt

Comment: @nas Which "natsort" did you use? From my link?